# getting an espacial part of a string in c++

Tags: c++, python

how can I get an especial part of a string or an array or a vector in C++?
in python it is in this way:

```
a = "hello"     #string
b = [1,2,3,4,5]     #list
a[1:4]     #from index 1 to 4
b[2:4]     #from index 2 to 4
```

result:

```
"ell"
[3,4]
```

is there any such syntax for C++?

Comment: It's called a  "substring", and yes, you can do it in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: what about array or vector?

Comment: What do you want to do with the slice? In C++ you sometimes need to consider efficiency as copies may be made, unlike in Python.

Comment: would you mind explaining more about copies that you said?

Comment: @CasillassReal: The copying is very real. `.substr` will make a copy (in memory) of the substring. That is to say, you have both `Hello` and `ell` in memory, and changing the first does not alter the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `substr` method for strings:

```
 string a = "abcdef";
 string special = a.substr(1,3); // gets bcd
```

The `slice` for valarrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  valarray<int> foo (5);
  for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) foo[i]=i;

  valarray<int> bar = foo[slice(2,3,1)];

  cout << "slice(2,3,1): ";
  for (size_t n=0; n<bar.size(); n++)
      cout << bar[n] << ' ';
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
// Output: slice: 2,3,4
```

And `copy` algorithm for vectors and lists:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main () {
  int myints[]={1,2,3,4,5};
  std::vector<int> v (5);

  std::copy ( myints+1, myints+4, v.begin() );

  std::cout << "v contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
// output 2,3,4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing for `string` with substring

```
 string a = "hello";
 string special = a.substr(1,3);
 //you get ell
```

For vectors, you can do something like the following:

```
vector<int> b{1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> sepcial(b.begin()+2, b.begin() + 4);
//you get [3,4]
```

Comment: `reserve` doesn't work in this case, because it doesn't change the size of the vector. `resize` is needed instead.

Comment: @Zyx2000 thanks for that, I updated the post, better to not use reserve at all.

Comment: Doesnt even need a `std::copy()`, you can do it directly: `vector<int> special(b.begin()+2, b.begin()+4);` constructs it in one step.

Answer (score 2):

Read a good reference page on [C++ std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

You probably want

```
 std::string s = "Hello";
 std::string e = s.substr(1,3);
```

then `e` gets `"ell"`.

And I don"t call that a special syntax, but some standard library API.

Comment: The parameters for substr are different from the Python slice syntax.  Whereas the C++ parameters are a starting position and a length, the Python slice syntax is from one index to another: 

`s[1:3]` returns `"el"`.  Is there a way to do that in C++, where you slice between indices?

Answer (score 2):

For a more generic version, that works on all containers, see e.g. [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

This can be used to, for example, copy some items from part of a vector into a new vector:

```
std::vector<int> b = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

std::vector<int> sub;
std::copy(std::begin(b) + 2,  // Start at "index" 2
          std::begin(b) + 5,  // Copy until (but NOT including) index 5
          std::back_inserter(sub)); // `back_inserter` calls `push_back` on `sub`
```

After this, the vector `sub` will contain the list 3, 4, 5.

To learn more about the iterator functions, you can read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

---

If you want to copy N number of entries, instead of having to use first/one-beyond-last you could use [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n):

```
std::copy_n(std::begin(b) + 2,  // Start at "index" 2
            3,                  // Copy three items
            std::back_inserter(sub)); // `back_inserter` calls `push_back` on `sub`
```

The result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you're actually working with.

There are two different types of 'string', the c++ `string` class and the standard C-String.

The C-String is basically an array of characters, so you'd iterate over it with a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = Begin; i < Max; ++i) printf("%c", a[i]);
```

Alternatively you could do this with:

```
printf("%3s", &a[Begin]);
```

Where 3 is the number of characters you want...however for this to work, you'd have to know the part of the string you want at compile time (or construct the formatting string dynamically with sprintf.

If you wish to use the C++ `string` you can use the `substr` function.

```
string a = "hello";
string b = a.substr(1, 4);  //b is 'ello'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to accomplish is extract a string from within a string. Also known as a substring.

In C++, the std::string class facilitates this capability.

See the substr member function in the std::string class. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

A simple example:

```
void some_fuction() {
  std::string my_string("Hello");
  std::string my_sub_string(my_string.substr(1, 3)); // Will contain "ell"
}
```